# What's the correct folder structure for custom typings for this module?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have custom typings for a module called `@xmpp/client`. I am trying to add these to my TypeScript project, but cannot get the compiler to recognize the types for the module.

I have my typings in a folder called `types`, so my folder structure looks like so:

```
.
├── app.json
├── App.tsx
├── package.json
├── src
│   └── <snip>
├── types
│   └── @xmpp
│        └── client.d.ts
├── tsconfig.json
└── yarn.lock
```

I've tried a couple of different folder structures, like having `types/@xmpp/client/index.d.ts` and so on, but nothing as worked -- every time I compile, I get the error `Cannot find module '@xmpp/client'`.

My `tsconfig.json` is as follows:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "jsx": "react-native",
    "lib": ["dom", "esnext"],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmit": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types", "./types"]
  },
  "includes": ["src/**/*.{ts,tsx}", "types/**/*.d.ts"]
}
```

Can anyone spot anything obviously wrong with this setup? Does my `tsconfig.json` look correct, and how should I structure my `types` folder for a module with a slash in its name?

The custom typings are as follows:

```
import { EventEmitter } from "react-native";

declare module "@xmpp/client" {
  export function client(options: {
    service?: string;
    domain?: string;
    resource?: string;
    username?: string;
    password?: string;
    credentials?: (
      auth: ({ username: string, password: string }) => any,
      mechanism: string
    ) => any;
  }): XmppClient;

  type XmppClient = EventEmitter & {
    start: () => void;
    stop: () => void;
    send: (...args: any) => Promise<any>;
  };
  export function jid(): any;

  <snip>
}
```

Comment: Can you share the contents of `types/@xmpp/client.d.ts`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this comment from a similar GitHub issue on the TypeScript repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16785#issuecomment-311852273), one thing you need to do is move your `import`s inside of the body of `declare module '@xmpp/client' { ... }`, like so:

```
declare module '@xmpp/client' {
  import { EventEmitter } from "react-native";
  // ...and so on
}
```

You'll also need to correct the type signature for `options.credentials` in the `client` function.

```
auth: ({ username: string, password: string }) => any
```

should be something like:

```
auth: (params: { username: string, password: string }) => any
```

If the issue persists after fixing those, then the issue may be with your `tsconfig`, but it looks fine to me right now.